# "Scala Application" missing in Netbeans 8.0.2 Projects under Windows

Tags: scala, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have installed Scala, Netbeans 8.0.2 and all Scala plugins from *Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins* in Netbeans.

I also added the following Windows environment variable:

```
SCALA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\scala
```

And have the one below set correctly:

```
PATH: %SCALA_HOME%\bin
```

The problem is that when in Netbeans I choose *File > New Project*, under Scala I only see *Scala Sbt Project*. I don't see *Scala Application*.

Why?

In NetBeans, if I go in *Tools > Scala Platforms*, I see a long list of Classes under the *Classes* tab but nothing under the *Sources* tab. Could this be it? I tried to manually add the JAR folder *"C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\lib"* but no luck.

EDIT: I uninstalled NetBeans v8.0.2 and installed NetBeans v7.4, downloaded the plugins from http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/files/nb-scala/, installed manually rather than from "Available Plugins" and now I see the "Scala Application" template.